# Why does $h\circ f_{n}\to h\circ f$ when $h$ is continuous and $f_n\to f$ pointwise?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, pointwise-convergence

Let $(X,d_{X})$ be a metric space, and for every integer $n\geq 1$, let $f_{n}:X\to\textbf{R}$ be a real-valued function. Suppose that $f_{n}$ converges pointwise to another function $f:X\to\textbf{R}$ on $X$ (in this question we give $\textbf{R}$ the standard metric $d(x,y) = |x-y|$). Let $h:\textbf{R}\to\textbf{R}$ be a continuous function. Show that the functions $h\circ f_{n}$ converge pointwise to $h\circ f$ on $X$, where $h\circ f_{n}:X\to\textbf{R}$ is the function $h\circ f_{n}(x) = h(f_{n}(x))$, and similarly for $h\circ f$.

**MY ATTEMPT**

My argument is the following: since for each fixed $x\in X$, the sequence $f_{n}(x)$ is a convergent sequence of real numbers which converges to $f(x)$, and continuous functions map convergent sequences onto convergent sequences, we conclude that $h(f_{n}(x))\to h(f(x))$, and we are done.

Am I missing any formal step or my argument is fine?

Comment: By the continuity of $h,$ we can push the limit inside, i.e., $\lim_n h(f_n(x)) = h(\lim_n f_n(x))$ for all $x.$ Consequently, the convergence of $f_n$ to $f$ gives the desired result.

Comment: Ultimately, your argument is fine, but I would write it in the way that I have.